# Jar File Missing File Path

Tags: java, filepath

Everything works fine while my ide is open, but when i build my project  it's not working as jar file. I guess the problem is at the path of my resource, I can't find any way to handle this problem, please help me if you have any solution.

```
public void playSound(String filename){

        String strFilename = filename;

        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            soundFile = new File(classLoader.getResource(strFilename).getFile());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

Comment: please show the StackTrace

Comment: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement:@2b5a780     <<<< StackTrace

Comment: @user3704324 That's not a stacktrace. See the `e.printStackTrace();` line? Please edit your question to include the output of that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot address a resource in your jar as a File. In your IDE it likely is a file in the file system, not a resource in a jar. You need to be able to read the content as a URL and/or InputStream.

Comment: But when I build my project, Jar file keeps my .wav resource inside itself, how I can adjust path then?

Comment: The "filename" argument must be relative to your classpath (i.e. where it lands in your jar). If you are using standard maven project structure, it would be relative to /src/main/resources. The classLoader.getResource portion of your code is fine. It is when you try to turn that resource into a file that you are having problems.